# c programming #define struct { } declaring

Tags: c, glibc

I was looking at Glibc codes. Some codes of glibc's queue caught my attention. I couldn't give a meaning to this struct definition. This struct doesn't have a name. Why? How does it work?

```
#define LIST_ENTRY(type)                        \
struct {                                \
    struct type *le_next;   /* next element */          \
    struct type **le_prev;  /* address of previous next element */  \
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/sys/queue.h#L92)

Comment: Looks like a substitute for a template.

Comment: In many cases macros express *partial* code. Look at how this macro is *used* later in the code to see the complete construct. There, I'm sure, you will see the missing name and all that's necessary.

Comment: Note that the header you referenced directs people to [the manual page for `queue`(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/queue.3.html) for usage documentation.  Did you read that page?  It indeed gives explanations, usage instructions, and example code for this macro and the others in that file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is actually a preprocessor macro, that could be expanded (most probably with trailing name) somewhere else.

In the comments at the start of that header file there is a reference to [queue(3) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/queue.3.html) that contains more details on that and other macros:

> The macro LIST_ENTRY declares a structure that connects the elements
>   in the list.

And an example of use:

> ```
> LIST_HEAD(listhead, entry) head = LIST_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);  
> struct listhead *headp;                 /* List head. */
> struct entry {  
>   ...  
>   LIST_ENTRY(entry) entries;      /* List. */  
>   ...  
> }  
> *n1, *n2, *n3, *np, *np_temp;  
>
> LIST_INIT(&head);                       /* Initialize the list. */  
>
> n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));      /* Insert at the head. */   
> LIST_INSERT_HEAD(&head, n1, entries);
> ```

Being this C code (not C++), and C lacks templates, this preprocessor macro can be used to "simulate" templates (note the `type` parameter).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, edited to provide better and more complete example of usage.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My comment no longer made sense after the question was edited, so I deleted it.

Comment: @epoxxy If it helped you, please, accept the answer by hitting the tick sign near it

Answer (score 7):

It's a macro that is used to declare a struct type, with `next` and `prev`  pointers to instances of a second struct type. That second type can be a parent type, so you can make a "linkable struct" like this:

```
struct foo {
  LIST_ENTRY(foo) list;
  int value;
};
```

This creates a `struct foo` containing a member called `list` which in turn is the structure in the question, with the pointers pointing at `struct foo`.

We can now create a little linked list of `struct foo`s like so:

```
struct foo fa, fb;
fa.value = 47;
fa.list.le_next = &fb;
fa.list.le_prev = NULL;
fb.value = 11;
fb.list.le_next = NULL;
fb.list.le_prev = &fa.list.le_next;
```

I'm not 100% sure about the last line, but I think it kind of makes sense.

Comment: Since you gave the identifier `list` to the list member in `struct foo`, you'd need to use `fa.list.le_next` rather than `fa.le_next` (and similarly for `le_prev`). You could, however, make the list member anonymous by declaring it as `LIST_ENTRY(foo);`, and then you could access `fa.le_next` and `fa.le_prev`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks! Fixed, of course. Also OMG, aren't anonymous members C11? :)

Comment: Note that sys/quque.h also comes with macros to add/remove/etc. from such a list (documented at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/queue.3.html)

Comment: I think the anonymous struct member variation is an even more likely usage model than the named struct variation.  The macro can support both, of course.

Comment: I guess the non-anonymous version would be more portable, but several pre-C11 compilers support anonymous members too.